# Why do I have to download the rdp file every time I stop and restart my Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, rdp

I created a Azure VM and to save money I'm stopping it when I'm not using it.
But it seems like every time I do this, my .rdp file stops working, giving me an error when trying to connect and I have to download it again from Azure Virtual Machine portal page.

Is this typical or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that after your restart (stop\start) the vm it public will most likely change (99.9% certainty). To work around that fact assign a DNS name to the IP and use the DNS name in your RDP file or convert the IP to static (but this is a bit more expensive)

Comment: thanks, how much more expensive is it to assign a DNS name label to it? Currently I'm using a 2 vcore, 8 Gib machine at ~$90/month. But ideally I'd like to up it to a 4 vCore machine, I just can't find one in the list for the same price or cheaper. I'm in the West US and don't know if searching for a machine in the South Pacific or else where would be any better/cheaper?

Comment: DNS mapping to IP should be free of cost. public static IP costs you about 4 dollars per month. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/

Comment: oh that's not bad! Do you know if there are any 4 core 8+ Gb Ram allocations for around $100/month. THe cheapest 4 core solution I found was $170/month

Comment: this is a completely different question. dns is free.